# php file not receiving data from axios post request

Tags: php, reactjs, axios

`php` file not receiving data from `axios` post request. Shows undefined error after form submit. I have created form in react `js`. All fields and state variables are properly showing.

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://tulisuites.com/form.php',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
  data:JSON.stringify(this.state)
})
  .then(result => {
    this.setState({
      mailSent: result.data.sent
    });
    console.dir(this.state);
  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({ error: error.message }));
```

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS");
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");

$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);

$subject = "Enquiry form";
$to = "sample@domainname.com";
// data

$msg = $_POST['name'] . $_POST['email'] . $_POST['organisation'] . $_POST['contactno'] . $_POST['message'];

// Headers

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers.= "From: <admin@tulisuites.com>";
mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Since  `$_POST` is a superglobal variable, you should be able to recieve your data directly from `$_POST`, or use `$_REQUEST` to obtain all methods. In my mind, there is no need to use `file_get_contents("php://input");`.

Comment: @JakobKronsteiner PHP only populates $_POST, if the Content-Type of the request was either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`. Here it is `application/json`, so this needs to be read directly from the raw input stream.

Comment: So what does the JSON you are sending actually look like?

Comment: @misorude  Ok, thanks for update. Had no situation like that before. So we need to see the json-data as asked before. Thx

Answer (score -3):

If you sent your data to server in proper JSON format through ajax, it should already be in your global `$_POST` variable. You can make sure you are getting the data by using `var_dump($_POST)` to see its content. If it contains your data, there is no need to read values from input stream, decoding it and then overwriting your global variable, you can just use this line:

```
$msg = $_POST['name'] . $_POST['email'] . $_POST['organisation'] . $_POST['contactno'] . $_POST['message'];
```

And it should work.

Additionally, you can use `filter_input(INPUT_POST, "variable")` for each of your parameters instead of `$_POST["variable"]` to make sure they are set and to prevent errors.

Comment: _“If you sent your data to server in proper JSON format through ajax, it should already be in your global $_POST variable.”_ - no, it should not. PHP only populates $_POST for requests with Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.